# Why is the lens eye of Deadshot reversed in Suicide Squad?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In all the adaptations of Deadshot, I have always notices the lens/patch on his right eye:

[Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(TV_series))

[image: Arrow]

[Smallville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallville)

[image: Smallville]

[Justice League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_(TV_series))

[image: Justice League]

This his how he is portrayed in the [comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadshot):

[image]

But in the upcoming film [Suicide Squad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_Squad_(film)), the lens is on his left eye:

[image]

Why is the lens eye changed from right to left for the upcoming film? Is there any reason behind this or is it just random?

Comment: BCdotWeb is probably closest. Numerous people have noticed the same thing, but no official statements have been released regarding it. Try tweeting at David Ayer or Will Smith and see what they have to say.

Comment: @JonathanHall https://twitter.com/Ankit_aries15/status/702230142307807232

Answer (score 12):

No official explanation AFAIK, but [this theory seems likely](http://screenrant.com/suicide-squad-movie-deadshot-mask-costume/):

> It’s also pleasant to see that Ayer and his costume team have realized
>   that **the actual mechanics of placing an augmented eye… device into the
>   scope of a rifle could prove a little clunky, or redundant**. As a
>   result, it will be Smith’s left eye sporting the visual boost. Either
>   that, or Smith is simply more dominant in one eye over the other
>   (unlike Deathstroke, Deadshot isn’t considered to have one eye
>   ‘missing,’ but either a cybernetically-enhanced eye, or both intact,
>   depending on the writer).

Comment: Nice theory,+1. But i will wait for some more accurate reason